# Heroku Deploy War with Jetty Runner

Tags: heroku, jetty, heroku-toolbelt

I'm looking for the way to deploy my app in Heroku with Jetty Runner. By not using Heroku Git ([Deploy your application to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner#deploy-your-application-to-heroku)
) as way of deployment.

```
heroku war:deploy <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
```

Will run the war with Tomcat Web Runner according to this documentation [Deployment with the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-cli).

> The Heroku CLI Deploy Plugin deploys a local WAR file to Heroku and
>   runs it with Tomcat Webapp-Runner

I would like to know if there's a Jetty Runner equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner#run-your-application) is the one from heroku devcenter.

- Ensure you have your ***P***rocfile created as mentioned in the article
- Optinally ensure to run `heroku ps:scale web=1` to allocate a dyno to your project